# Grails 3 with detached criteria predicate

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

How can I create a detached predicate to send to a method and then do the search with criteria?

Something like this:

```
def predicate = { eq 'field1', 1 }    
search(predicate)
```

--

```
def search(predicate) {
    
    return SampleClass.withCriteria() {
        predicate
        eq 'field2', 2
        eq 'field2', 3
    }.find()

}
```

There is a way to do that to avoid ifs inside the criteria?

Comment: Your code sample is using the criteria api and the title mentions detached criteria. 
 Which would you prefer?

Comment: criteria api...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches you could take.  One is represented in the project at [github.com/jeffbrown/victorsoarescriteria](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorsoarescriteria).

[grails-app/domain/victorsoarescriteria/SampleClass.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorsoarescriteria/blob/d2169fc364c95a8938640265920e7eac4914f85c/grails-app/domain/victorsoarescriteria/SampleClass.groovy)

```
package victorsoarescriteria

class SampleClass {
    String name
    String country
    int someNumber
}
```

[grails-app/init/victorsoarescriteria/BootStrap.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorsoarescriteria/blob/d2169fc364c95a8938640265920e7eac4914f85c/grails-app/init/victorsoarescriteria/BootStrap.groovy)

```
package victorsoarescriteria

import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        initData()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }

    @Transactional
    void initData() {
        new SampleClass(name: 'Jeff', country: 'United States', someNumber: 42).save()
        new SampleClass(name: 'Jake', country: 'United States', someNumber: 21).save()
        new SampleClass(name: 'Bill', country: 'United Kingdom', someNumber: 27).save()

        def greaterThanFive = search {
            gt 'someNumber', 5
        }
        println "greaterThanFive.size() is ${greaterThanFive.size()}"
        def greaterThanTwentyFive = search {
            gt 'someNumber', 25
        }
        println "greaterThanTwentyFive.size() is ${greaterThanTwentyFive.size()}"
    }

    def search(predicate) {
       SampleClass.withCriteria {
           predicate.delegate =  delegate
           predicate()
       }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
~ $ git clone git@github.com:jeffbrown/victorsoarescriteria.git && cd victorsoarescriteria && ./gradlew bootRun
Cloning into 'victorsoarescriteria'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 113, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (113/113), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (85/85), done.
remote: Total 113 (delta 15), reused 113 (delta 15), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (113/113), 803.93 KiB | 3.77 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (15/15), done.

> Task :bootRun

greaterThanFive.size() is 3
greaterThanTwentyFive.size() is 2

Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
```

Comment: Of course inside of the `withCriteria` closure you could have whatever additional criteria you like (`eq 'field2', 2`, etc.).